# Json response to HTML values AJAX

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to set action.php response to HTML fields via AJAX.i am calling ajax and trying to fetch data from database (action.php) and set it to HTML fields.

Here is my code :

action.php :

```
 $arr_data=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$arr_data['image1'] = $row['name'];
$arr_data['web_name'] = $row['web_name'];
$arr_data['web_link'] = $row['web_link'];
$arr_data['linked_img'] = $row['linked_img'];
$arr_data['description'] = $row['description'];

 }
 echo json_encode($arr_data);
```

AJAX CALL :

```
     $.ajax({
   url:"getchange.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{image_id:image_id},
      success:function(data)
      {

     var obj = JSON.parse(this.data);
     alert("obj");
      // $('#name').val(obj.web_name);
      // $('#name').val("update");
    }
    })
```

HTML :

```
   <div id="imageModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Website</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="image_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p><label>Name : </label>     <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  />
      </p>
     <p><label>Select Linked Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="image" id="image" /></p><br />
    <p><label>Add Link</label>
     <input type="text" name="link" id="link" /></p><br />
         <p><label>Add Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="image2" id="image2" /></p><br />

          <p><label>Add Description</label>
     <textarea name="desc" rows="10" cols="50" id="desc" ></textarea></p><br />
     <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="insert" />
     <input type="hidden" name="image_id" id="image_id" />
     <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-info" />

    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What i wanted to achieve is that : i can fetch database row via ajax and set values="row record" to HTML fields . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to update 1 or more existing rows in HTML, or are you wanting to add new row(s) with the AJAX response data using a template for a row ?  If you have the HTML that would be helpful.  If you use a dataType of json in your AJAX I don't think you have to parse the response.  It will be json.

Comment: Question updated , thanks for your time .

Comment: i am trying to work on "update button" using HTML models . so , if someone click on Update button , it opens this model but i want to place data as well , when someone is updating records .

Comment: You can iterate through a simple object with for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(jsonresponse)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}.  If you are trying to set the form values programmiaically that may be a problem with the input type="file".  If you want to create a new element that is not a form you could do that and just summarizes your data you could do that.  See this also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777779/programmatically-set-input-type-file-value-to-base64-image

Answer (score 1):

first you should change your `url:"getchange.php"` to `url:"action.php"` in Ajax code because you're processing data on `action.php` so you should post data to this file.
and second I assumed that you wanna insert data into some input forms like this in `index.html` or whatever you want:

```
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="web_name">
    <input type="text" name="web_link">
    <input type="text" name="linked_img">
    <input type="text" name="description">
```

and here is the `action.php` file :

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
   url: "getchange.php",
   method: "GET",   
   success: function(data) {
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(data);
     document.getElementByName('name').value = data.image1;
     document.getElementByName('web_name').value = data.web_name;
     document.getElementByName('web_link').value = data.web_link;
     document.getElementByName('linked_img').value = data.linked_img;
     document.getElementByName('description').value = data.description;

   }
 })
});
</script>
```

as you can see for example `data.image1` is what you are pass from `action.php`.and you also should use `GET` method because you are not posting any data. you are just retrieving some data.

Hope be useful and have great positive time ^_^

Comment: Hy thank you very much for your answer but it is not working for me . 1. changed to action.php 2. also when i try to do this "alert(data.web_link);" it is saying undefined

Comment: @MuneebQureshi I tested the code on my localhost and it works great but I filled the array `$arr_data` with some fake data. don't forget to use `data = JSON.parse(data);` and `console.log(data)` . hope work ^_^

Comment: I think you have to add another parameter to your ajax call `dataType=html` it may be worked. Im not tested it yet.